# Why # is not allowed in an identifier?

Tags: java, identifier

Java allows identifier to start with or contain $ (dollar sign).
e.g int a$b;

But why # is not allowed in an identifier? What is the specific reason? Is # an operator or something in Java?
e.g int a#b;

Comment: Because that's the way they designed it. I've used a lot of programming languages since 1971 and I've never seen one that allowed '#' in an identifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say that it is a combination of readability and the historical antecedents of the language.  Remember that the Java syntax was designed to be easy-on-the-eye for C and C++ programmers.  (And as @dan04 points out, the `#` character is significant in most dialects of C and C++.)

Incidentally, while `$` is technical legal in Java identifiers, it is reserved for use by compilers, code generators and other things.  If you use `$` in identifiers in your source code, you risk getting into trouble with collisions with synthetic identifiers produced by (for example) the `javac` compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there was a specific reason for disallowing `#` as much as there was a general aversion to punctuation in identifiers (which could *look* like operators).  Special exceptions were made in order to deal with WORD_SEPARATION and Inner$Classes.

In C and C++, on which Java's syntax is based, `#` is used for [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) directives.

Answer (score 1):

[Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) can contain letters, digits, underscores and dollar signs - excluding #, @, ~ ,`

I guess this is for the sake of readability - `int s#@t;` seems odd.